# Deezer api search url album cover is missing

Tags: json, image, api, search, deezer

Since two days we got a problem with the Deezer Api on this url:

http://api.deezer.com/search/autocomplete?q=Jean

In the object returned, some fields are now missing in the album object and in the base object.
The fields which usually contain the images disappeared.

```
      {
    "id": 122440564,
    "readable": true,
    "title": "Aloha",
    "title_short": "Aloha",
    "title_version": "",
    "link": "http://www.deezer.com/track/122440564",
    "duration": 218,
    "rank": 0,
    "explicit_lyrics": false,
    "preview": "http://cdn-preview-9.deezer.com/stream/9f7248e8744c135d4878ae851d8bb881-4.mp3",
    "artist": {
      "id": 5542423,
      "name": "Møme",
      "link": "http://www.deezer.com/artist/5542423",
      "picture": "http://api.deezer.com/artist/5542423/image",
      "picture_small": "http://cdn-images.deezer.com/images/artist/6054372bc5d6dc0a2d355d5a2d55242a/56x56-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_medium": "http://cdn-images.deezer.com/images/artist/6054372bc5d6dc0a2d355d5a2d55242a/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_big": "http://cdn-images.deezer.com/images/artist/6054372bc5d6dc0a2d355d5a2d55242a/500x500-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_xl": "http://cdn-images.deezer.com/images/artist/6054372bc5d6dc0a2d355d5a2d55242a/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/artist/5542423/top?limit=50",
      "type": "artist"
    },
    "album": {
      "id": 12811488,
      "title": "Aloha",
      "tracklist": "http://api.deezer.com/album/12811488/tracks",
      "type": "album"
    },
    "type": "track"
  },
```

I checked in the Deezer Api documentation, and apparently the version doesn't change, and, based on the documentation, the album object normally contain the cover album:

http://developers.deezer.com/api/search/album

Did anyone got the same issue ? I tried to tweet them and I also sent an email to api@deezer.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed, we had some side effects that are now resolved.

Comment: Apparently a problem still happen, the albums section is always empty, is it normal ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, the autocomplete is still not working, we are fixing that quickly, sorry for the inconvenience!